# API not working for Javascript or REST, producing KeyError

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to replicate the Reverse Geocoding section in this article:
https://developer.here.com/blog/getting-started-with-geocoding-exif-image-metadata-in-python3

I've tried with creds for both Javascript and Rest. For the Javascript creds, I've copy-pasted the `app_id`. For `app_code` I'm using the "API KEY". For the REST creds, I've tried pairing the `app_id` with both the "API KEY" and the "ACCESS KEY ID".

Both produce a `KeyError: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of trickiness involved, due to the fact that *app_id* and *app_code* pair have been deprecated in favor of *apiKey*. The blog post was written before that change.

So if you created your HERE project recently and have an api key instead of an *app_id* and *app_code* pair, you need to:

1. Replace *app_id* and *app_code* parameters with *apiKey* instead, with the value accordingly
2. Check and adjust the endpoint url (***.api.here.com*** became ***.ls.hereapi.com***)

See below:

```py
#uri = 'https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json'
uri = 'https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json'
headers = {}
params = {
    #'app_id': os.environ['APP_ID_HERE'],
    #'app_code': os.environ['APP_CODE_HERE'],
    'apiKey': os.environ['API_KEY_HERE'],
    'prox': "%s,%s" % coords,
    'gen': 9,
    'mode': 'retrieveAddresses',
    'maxresults': 1,
}
```

See also the **[documentation examples for reverse geocode](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoder/reverse-geocode)**

Comment: I'm able to get a response through CURL using my API key but Python produces a `KeyError`. I have copy-pasted your code and inserted this API key, leaving `app_id` and `app_code` commented out. Suggestions?

Comment: The python example is using `os.environ` to get the key from the environment variables, and assumes you have set up your key as an environment variable.
Did you make sure the key is retrieved properly from the environment variables? You can also bypass this step and paste the key directly in the script.